# How to use IHostingEnvironment in a class file

Tags: c#, .net-core

In .NET framework I would have just used Server.MapPath(). In .NET Core 2.2, I understand I should be using `IHostingEnvironment`. But every example I can find seems to assume I'm using it in a controller. And these examples say to inject IHostingEnvironment in the controller. But...

In my case, I am using some *.json files as data repositories. I am creating an independent Data Access class that can be called from multiple upstream locations. I'm not grasping how to inject IHostingEnvironment into this class without impacting the upstream callers.  The idea is, if we someday swap out the .json files for a SQL table, then we want to only make changes to the Data Access class, and not to any of the sources which call it.

So, how, in the Data Access class, can I map a path to a local .json file?

```
namespace DataAccess
{
    public class Repository
    {
        private readonly string _connStringName;

        public Repository(string connStringName)
        {
            _connStringName = connStringName;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>()
        {
            IEnumerable<T> entities;
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(_connStringName)) // <---- ??
            {
                string json = r.ReadToEnd();
                entities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json);
            }
            return entities;
        }
    }
}
```

This line:

```
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(_connStringName))
```

wants to map a path to IIS Express, which I understand. But I need it to map a path to the relative location of the file.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Maybe I am doing this wrong? This is how I was trying to follow the examples I saw:

```
public class Repository
{

    private readonly string _connStringName;
    private IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public Repository(string connStringName, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        _connStringName = connStringName;
        _hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }

    // rest of the class
}
```

If I do it this way, every upstream location that creates an instance of `Repository` now has to pass `IHostingEnvironment' into it.

**EDIT 2:**

How `Repository` is being used.

```
public static class Customers
{
    private static readonly string _connStringName = "customer.json";

    public static string Get()
    {
        DataAccess.Repository repository = new DataAccess.Repository(_connStringName);
        List<Customer> customers = repository.GetList<Customer>().ToList();
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customers);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are upstream callers affected by injecting `IHostingEnvironment`? Surely that's a detail they don't know about (since I'd expect `Repository` to be injected into them)?

Comment: @John, see the edit to my OP.  Thanks!

Comment: @John, 'Repository` is not injected into anything.

Comment: (I'll be the first to admit, DI is NOT my strong point)

Comment: Can you show how `Repository` is being used? And are you using DI elsewhere in your project?

Comment: @John, yes!  See edit #2

Comment: @John, "And are you using DI elsewhere in your project?" No.

Comment: That's harder to answer then. I don't think there is a good solution that doesn't affect callers, unless you have a general configuration object that works for both scenarios, and then just pass that in. I might be biased, but I'd definitely recommend looking into DI. It does simplify a lot of these kinds of things since most callers don't need to know about how to construct a service, they just receive it through their constructor. I'll try to put something together as an answer later if I have time :-)

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Core project?

Comment: @gldraphael, yes. Core 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET Core you can register your dependencies to be injected at startup.

If you do it this way, you will need to:

1. inject `Repository` into `Customers`.
2. pass `Repository` dependencies in Startup

```
// Startup.cs
public class Startup
{
    // ...
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // [2]
        var connectionString = "customer.json"; // or get from a config file
        services.AddSingleton<Repository>(new Repository(connectionString, env));
    }
    // ...
}

public class Customers
{
    private Repository _repository;
    public Customers(Repository repository)
    {
        // [1]
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public string Get()
    {
        // you can use _repository here without passing stuff in
    }
}

public class Repository
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;
    public Repository(string connectionString, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }
}
```

.NET Core Dependency Injection - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: awesome! Going to dig into this until I understand it

Comment: Great! Also if you don't mind some extra work, it is best practice to use `Interfaces` over `Classes` when passing in dependencies. This makes everything loosely coupled.